# 'invalid HTTP proxy (http://localhost:4001 ): bad URI' error adding a GPG key 

Tags: proxy, tor

I m installing tor I got gpg error

**i have install tor just 15 mint ago on my vm & it was working perfect**

http://www.webupd8.org/2009/09/how-to-install-tor-in-ubuntu-debian.html

1. Adding the GPG key and installing TOR and Privoxy in Ubuntu / Debian. Open a terminal and paste this:

GPG error

```
root@onezero:/home/one# gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv 886DDD89
gpg: requesting key 886DDD89 from hkp server keys.gnupg.net
?: invalid HTTP proxy (http://localhost:4001 ): bad URI
gpgkeys: HTTP fetch error 7: couldn't connect: Success
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
gpg: Total number processed: 0
```

Comment: vm is on my laptop & right now i m installing it on my desktop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was failing because I was using a proxy server, I have disable it and it worked.

After disabling the network proxy on the network tool this was solved

[image]

Comment: just edit your answer cauzz u have diagnose the problem .. i didnt

Comment: to me just a luck i did that

Comment: No matter, just mark it answered, that's the most important thing, regards.

Comment: @BrunoPereira u sould edit your answer thats it , its cauzz of proxy problem ... thankyou 4 diagnose the problem